# Which portion of boot.log files are binary?

Tags: linux, grep, logs, cat, binary

My system keeps seemingly randomly failing to boot after a kernel update. So I am reading logs to try to determine the cause of the issue. Here is one of the boot logs:

```bash
$ sudo cat /var/log/boot.log.1
------------ Sat Aug 26 12:45:00 GMT 2023 ------------
/dev/mapper/linux--vg-root: clean, 1261921/90649104 files, 50539269/60917669 blocks
[  OK  ] Finished plymouth-read-write.service - Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data.
[  OK  ] Finished systemd-binfmt.service - Set Up Additional Binary Formats.
         Starting binfmt-support.service - Enable support for additional executable binary formats...
[  OK  ] Finished systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service - Create Volatile Files and Directories.
[  OK  ] Started resolvconf.service - Nameserver information manager.
[  OK  ] Reached target network-pre.target - Preparation for Network.
         Starting systemd-update-utmp.service - Record System Boot/Shutdown in UTMP...
[  OK  ] Finished systemd-update-utmp.service - Record System Boot/Shutdown in UTMP.
[  OK  ] Finished binfmt-support.service - Enable support for additional executable binary formats.
[  OK  ] Finished apparmor.service - Load AppArmor profiles.
[  OK  ] Started haveged.service - Entropy Daemon based on the HAVEGE algorithm.
         Starting networking.service - Raise network interfaces...
         Starting snapd.apparmor.service - Load AppArmor profiles managed internally by snapd...
(Redacted)
[  OK  ] Started snapd.service - Snap Daemon.
         Starting snapd.seeded.service - Wait until snapd is fully seeded...
```

However when I try to filter the lines that failed, `grep` refuses to display.

```bash
$ sudo cat /var/log/boot.log.1 | grep "FAILED"
grep: (standard input): binary file matches
```

Only when I enable `-a` can I view the output.

```bash
$ sudo cat /var/log/boot.log.1 | grep -a "FAILED"
[FAILED] Failed to start apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server.
```

I don't see any binary in `cat` output. Where is it? On a side note, could `apache` be the culprit of the boot failures?

Comment: 1. Are those lines colourised? (e.g. "OK" in green or "FAILED" in red).   Colour codes contain at least one ESC character, which grep classifies as binary, not plain text.  as you discovered, `grep -a` is the solution to grepping things that are "mostly text".  2. What, exactly, do you mean by "seemingly randomly failing to boot "? What's the exact behaviour? freeze or lockup? boot loop? everything but apache working fine?  apache failing to start is not what I would call "failed to boot", it's just one daemon out of many that failed to start (possibly due to configuration problems).

Answer (score 1):

If your system crashes just as it is writing into a log file, with some filesystem types, you can end up with a block or so of NULs (i.e. ASCII zero bytes) where the end of file was at that point. That will usually make `grep` treat the file as a binary file.

When recovering the filesystem journal after the crash, the filesystem may have allocated the block for the log file, but lost the actual data that was supposed to be written there (e.g. with an `ext4` filesystem in a `journal_data_writeback` mode). Since the filesystem does not know the actual length of the lost data (full block or something less?) nor whether the exact location of particular data in the file is important or not, it ends up filling up such blocks with missing data with zero bytes.

Another possible reason is if you use a non-UTF8 locale, and some log message contains characters that are not part of the character set you're using: that might also lead `grep` from treating the file as binary.

Comment: In either case, this is mostly harmless and grep is just being annoying and `-a` is the correct solution.  (Thie potentionally missing log data might be a sad loss...)